# Why can't I access facebook friend locations through koala API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, coffeescript, omniauth, koala

Before I begin I should say that I have read and tried many suggested solutions to my problem and none of them has solved it, so I am going to ask again and be very specific.

I am doing facebook login integration into a rails 4 app using omniauth 1.1.4 omniauth-facebook 1.4.0 with koala 1.7.0rc1 to interact with the graph API. I am doing it exactly as in [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/360-facebook-authentication) railcast.

My problem is that when I request the user's facebook friends via koala like so

```
@current_friends = graph.get_connections('me', 'friends?fields=location,name,id')
```

the returned friends hashes contain no `location` field. I tried updating my coffeescript login call like:

```
$('#fb_login').click (e) ->
   e.preventDefault()
   FB.login ((response) ->
     window.location = '/auth/facebook/callback' if response.authResponse), scope: "friends_location"
```

but that didn't do anything. Then I tried, with the coffeescript modification and without, passing a scope parameter in my facebook omniauth initializer:

```
provider :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID'], ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET'], :scope => 'friends_location'
```

No difference. I tried deleting the coffeescript altogether and allowing the full redirect; I tried switching the **Auth Token Parameter** field on my app's facebook console between server and client side; I tried basically every combination of these things, but still nothing. Finally, I should note that when I call

```
graph.get_connections('me', 'permissions')
```

the returned permission list has `friends_location=1`. So what is going on?

Comment: has my answer been helpful?

Answer (score 0):

You should add to scope `read_friendlists` permission:

```
provider :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID'], ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET'], :scope => 'read_friendlists, friends_location'
```